# How to force Visual Studio to use x64 DNX SDK architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm using 1.0.0-beta7 x64 but visual studios insists I'm using x86.  When I delete all my runtimes except the one I'm targeting I get this:

[image]

I can't find a reference to x86 anywhere in my project.

[image]

When I hover over the Solution DNX SDK version here it shows the x86 version but I don't know where it's getting this from. Currently this isn't causing any problems I'm just trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: look for a web.config file in the wwwroot folder, it has appsettings that are used to bootstrap the runtime

Comment: @JoeAudette there is no web.config. I thought that was a thing of the past. Searched wwwroot and sub folders just in case but there was no web.config.

Comment: if you create a new web app in vs2015 with beta 7 tooling it will add a web.config either upon build or publish. and there will also be a wwwroot/bin folder with a single dll used to bootstrap the runtime. However that is going away in beta8 with the new hosting model. I only commented because at one time I also had a case where it was not using the intended runtime and it was caused by the web.config. maybe your case is different.

Comment: I see.  Looks like I've hit a different issue.  Most likely something that will get ironed out during the beta ).

Comment: do `dnvm list` and check what is your default runtime. It can be that the runtime whose alias is `default` does not exist. Close vs and alias the x64 runtime as your default (i.e. `dnvm alias default 1.0.0-beta8 -arch x64 -r clr`) open VS and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Tried this as I didn't have a default alias but alas it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click in your, **web** (not solution) project and select Properties. Click "Use Specific Runtime" and pick the dnx runtime that you want from the dropdown. All this does is set the "sdkVersion" in the /Properties/launchSettings.json of your project.

[image: Set project specific dnx runtime]

The ["sdk"](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DesignNote-19th-Jan-2015) in your global.json indicates the minimum sdk version that the project will run but won't run your project against it. It'll take the setting you have in launchSettings.json instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but I've also tried this and it makes no difference.  I still get the error message.

Comment: Whaat does your launchSettings.json look like?

Comment: {
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
      },
      "sdkVersion": "dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7"
    }
  }
}

Comment: I don't think you can force Visual Studio to use x64 as it uses it internally for the tooling to work. Since Visual Studio is running 32-bit, it can't load any x64 references. You can, however, use the above to force the architecture to x64 when you publish it.

Comment: Ahh, Didn't think about VS itself.  Yep it's 32 bit.  I guess that's what it is. Thanks for the feed back.

Comment: This seems to have disappeared on 1.0.0 release... Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a 32bit Windows?

If not, I would then suggest you clean out your runtimes.

> C:\Users\USERNAME\.dnx\runtimes

Then do a fresh install `dnvm upgrade` or perhaps `dnvm install <version>`. Whilst you are at it you might as well update your dnvm as well `dnvm update-self`.

Then set your runtimes on the web project properties, and the global.json, to x64. 
If you are using IIS Express to debug, set to use 64 bit version of IIS Express.

[image: 64 bit]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm running 64bit windows and have tried all of the above but no luck.